# MSQL Insert multiple row from select statment with subquery and 1 value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want insert new data in my table with condition that i get from subquery here sample of table :

permission

```
role_id     permission_id
   1              1
   1              2
   1              3
   2              1
   2              3
   3              1
   3              2
   4              1
```

So, lets say role_id is a group of id that have more than 1 permission id that connected.
So i would like to insert new data that role_id doesn't have permission id 2. which are role_id 2 and 4

i would like to run this query :

```
INSERT INTO PERMISSION
VALUES ('2', '2')
VALUES ('4', '2');
```

in 1 query, i have try to run this query :

```
INSERT INTO permission(role_id, permission_id)
VALUES( 
    (select distinct(role_id) from role_permission rp2 
    where role_id NOT IN (
    select role_id from role_permission rp
    where permission_id = 2)),
    2);
```

but the result is it always get error :

```
SQL Error [1242] [21000]: Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

is there any way for inserting multiple query mix with 1 value using mysql ?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query is missing a comma and repeats `VALUES`.  I also recommend listing the columns

```
INSERT INTO PERMISSION (role_id, permission_id)
    VALUES ('2', '2'),
           ('4', '2');
```

Note that ids are usually numbers.  If that is the case, then remove the single quotes.

For the second query, use `INSERT . . . SELECT`"

```
INSERT INTO permission (role_id, permission_id)
    select rp.role_id, 2
    from role_permission rp
    group by rp.role_id
    having sum(rp.permission_id = 2) = 0;
```